# ArcGIS Online: lines are not displaying correctly on Esri Map Viewer mobile app

Tags: arcgis-online, line

I have a polyline shapefile uploaded to my ArcGIS Online Web Map that displays correctly via the web map and web app, but incorrectly (random shards and missing segments) in the Esri "Map Viewer" for mobile apps. Any idea what could be causing this?
[image: Correct Display via Web Map and Web App]

[image: Incorrect Display via Mobile App]

Comment: I know this is a little late to comment on this, but I was having the same issue (Kinda). I was trying to add a layer to my map of blueprints for schools. Each room in the school was its own polygon with attribute data. When I uploaded the shape file to ArcGIS Explorer online the square polygons were showing up as half squares (triangles) and what I ended up doing was the opposite of what you said. Instead of generalizing it I told it to stay the same and it worked. Thanks for the lead!

Answer (score 2):

I seemed to have figured this out: on AGOL, when adding a layer from a file (shapefile in a zipped folder) to your web map, you should choose "generalize features for web display" instead of "keep original features". This is the only way I could get the line to display properly via the mobile app.